# Finding the first blank row when you have multiple columns of varying length

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an interesting one (hopefully) for y'all and thanks in advance!!

I've got a report that I'm creating that will take tables from other workbooks and copy them to a single report page in the default book.

This is repeated until all workbooks have been scanned.  I use a LastRow and LastPos to maintain where I am on the sheet so as not to overwrite, but I find that some reports don't use columns that I'm trying to find the LastRow with.

So doing something like  `Range("A65536").End(xlup).Select` I have to check each report to see what the longest column is. It could be A or B or C or D?

What my question is, is there an easy way check these values and find the largest value so I can assign to a variable and use?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function for all of my "last" needs:

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(what:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(what:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(what:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(what:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Usage is like:

```
dim LR as Long
LR = Last(1,Sheet1.Cells)
```

Comment: Hi Sous: Looks good, but question...Looking at the code and seeing `rng.cells(1)` isn't that specifiying "A1" or does that indicate all cells?  Jeff

Comment: it's the first cell in the range that you pass it.  So you could do something like Last(1,Sheet1.Range("A5:J10") and return the last used cell in that range.

Comment: also to get the 1st empty row you'll need to add 1 to the result of the function.

Comment: Got it.... Seems to be working fine for me....and yes, figured out that I had to add 1 for rows....:)  Thanks again!